# Unsuccessful assembly of native Hadoop library on Solaris: build.xml doesn't exist

Tags: ant, hadoop, solaris

Operating it agrees https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-3123

```
root@one: /export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin# ant -Dcompile.native=true -Dnonspace.os=SunOS -Dmake.cmd=gmake clean tar
```

Also received as a result:

```
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!    
Build failed
```

Comment: I am also getting the same error